# Javascript window.open() returns null and opens in tab - Firefox only

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am opening a new window using the following code.

```
var windowX = window.open('/some-page', 'newWindowName', 'width=600,height=600');
```

This works on Chrome, and **did** work on Firefox but has suddenly stopped working on Firefox.

I have not changed any of the code, nor have I changed any browser settings, the browser has not been updated and remains on version 68.

The `window.open(...)` is now returning null and opening a blank page in a new tab.

Comment: You probably have popup blockers enabled

Comment: Same result with or without popup block enabled

Comment: I can't reproduce this in the console. What OS?

Comment: Windows 10, after closing and opening Firefox, it works again. I hope this isn't an issue regarding how long the main window is open for.

Comment: Weird! Sorry I can't help you.